# Mouse click not working on Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot

Tags: drivers, touchpad, hardware, button

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a dual boot with Windows 10. My laptop is a Dell Latitude 7480. Basically, my touchpad click buttons stopped working suddenly while I was using my laptop. The cursor movement and scrolling do work, usually. The right button has been working sporadically, and when it does, the two-finger tap on the touchpad works as well. My laptop is a touch screen and all the touch screen capabilities work. The keyboard works perfectly well too. When I switch to the Windows side of my dual boot, everything is the same -- no touchpad button clicking works, but everything else does.

Here is everything I have tried and what has happened:

- Rebooting my system -- nothing changes
- apt update && apt upgrade -- nothing changes
- Rebooting into recovering mode and doing all checks/cleans/updates -- nothing changes
- Turning touchpad off and on in settings, and toggling all other options -- nothing changes
- "Test your settings" under mouse and touchpad settings -- when I left click or tap on the touchpad, nothing registers. When right click is working and I right click or tap on the touchpad with two fingers, "secondary button click" registers. When I tap on it using touch screen, it registers as "primary button click."
- Switching the right button to primary button in settings -- sometimes this makes neither right nor left buttons work; sometimes this doesn't change the right button click action (it is still secondary button click).
- Uninstalling/purging/reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics -- nothing changes
- Switching to the Windows side and reinstalling drivers and devices there -- nothing changes
- Running hardware diagnostics on the Windows side -- nothing wrong is found
- Testing with a physical mouse -- nothing changes; same issue with the left click

Please let me know if there is anything else I should try, or if this is a hardware issue I should investigate with Dell. Thank you!

Comment: If it doesn't work with Windows and Ubuntu, it is a hardware issue.

Comment: To second what @Pilot6 said: your touchpad buttons are broken, and *will not work* unless you fix/replace them. No changes in Ubuntu or Windows will fix it for you.

Comment: It makes sense that it wouldn't be Ubuntu-specific, but the same issues (no primary button, limited secondary button) apply to all the different hardware I've tested besides the touchscreen (physical mouse, tap-to-click, AND touchpad button).

Comment: Try disabling the touchpad entirely from the driver THEN plugging an external mouse. If the touchpad is stuck at a permanent click, it will preclude your mouse clicks

Comment: Is the replacement external mouse known to work properly on another computer system? This absolutely sounds like a failing hardware touchpad. What laptop is it? You might want to try xmousekeys (control cursor with keyboard) until you can replace it.

Comment: It suddenly started working after restarting it a few times. A hardware guy said it may likely be a touchscreen issue, because it is refurbished and reinstalled touchscreens often cause issues with the clicking. I still have no idea how it started working again.